# calculating consecutive values of a variable in groups using a base year and growth rates in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, grouping

I'm currently working on a project where I need to calculate the consecutive values of a variable, given the base value and growth rates. The data looks something like this:

| Scode | Year | OfficialGDP | GDPMultiplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AGO | 1990 | 57.96 | 0.96 |
| AGO | 1991 | NA | 1.009 |
| AGO | 1992 | NA | 0.94 |
| AGO | 1993 | NA | 0.76 |
| AGO | 1994 | NA | 1.01 |
| AGO | 1995 | NA | 1.15 |
| TUR | 1990 | 65.4 | 1.20 |
| TUR | 1991 | NA | 1.03 |
| TUR | 1992 | NA | 0.94 |
| TUR | 1993 | NA | 0.76 |
| TUR | 1994 | NA | 1.01 |
| TUR | 1995 | NA | 1.15 |

What I want to do is to calculate the consecutive GDP values for each country and store it under the OfficialGDP column. For example 57.96 * 1.009 = 58.48 will be stored under 57.96 and I'll iterate the calculation and multiply 58.48 with 0.94. I should also do this for each unique country since all of them has a different base value. My hunch was to use a for loop iteration that allows for grouping (I want to group by Scode) but I couldn't find something helpful online. I also think the for loop function should include the following specification:

dat[j+1,4] <- dat[j,4] * dat[j+1,5]

(In the original dataframe OfficialGDP is stored in column 4 and multiplier is stored in column 5)

I hope my explanation is clear enough. I would appreciate all kinds of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Scode) %>%
  mutate(growth_cuml = cumprod(GDPMultiplier) / first(GDPMultiplier),
         GDP = first(OfficialGDP) * growth_cuml,
         # this is just to show the underlying number has more precision
         GDP_label = scales::comma(GDP, accuracy = 0.001)) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 12 × 7
   Scode  Year OfficialGDP GDPMultiplier growth_cuml   GDP GDP_label
   <chr> <int>       <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
 1 AGO    1990        58.0          0.96       1      58.0 57.960   
 2 AGO    1991        NA            1.01       1.01   58.5 58.482   
 3 AGO    1992        NA            0.94       0.948  55.0 54.973   
 4 AGO    1993        NA            0.76       0.721  41.8 41.779   
 5 AGO    1994        NA            1.01       0.728  42.2 42.197   
 6 AGO    1995        NA            1.15       0.837  48.5 48.527   
 7 TUR    1990        65.4          1.2        1      65.4 65.400   
 8 TUR    1991        NA            1.03       1.03   67.4 67.362   
 9 TUR    1992        NA            0.94       0.968  63.3 63.320   
10 TUR    1993        NA            0.76       0.736  48.1 48.123   
11 TUR    1994        NA            1.01       0.743  48.6 48.605   
12 TUR    1995        NA            1.15       0.855  55.9 55.895
```

Comment: This has been very helpfull, thanks!